# How to display the table on an external database (MySQL) in Express.js (using ejs)

Tags: mysql, express

I don't know the specific code to use in Express.js to exchange table information for an external database.
For example, what would the code for displaying a list of tables look like?

**postscript**
・If you go to the "/all/" page from the top page, the list will be displayed.
・If you write `const connection = mysql.createConnection({});` and set the IP address for host in {} to localhost, where do you specify the location of mysql?
・I am using ejs for the view engine, so please assume that we are using ejs.

**table**
[books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQYAD.png)

**./view/all.ejs/**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title><%=title %></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/all.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1><%=title %></h1>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="top">
    <div>
      <div><a href=<%= top %>>Topへ戻る</a></div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="output">
    <div>
      <p>一覧の表示</p>
      <table>
        <%- content %>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <div>
      <p><%= libraryName %></p>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: (ちなみに、日本語のStack Overflowもありますよ。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: If you have issues with your JS code, you need to show your JS code. Regarding `const connection = mysql.createConnection({});` - if you pass an empty object `{}` then default values will be used for `host` and `port`. The defaults are `host: 'localhost'` and `port: 3306`, which is where a standard local MySQL server installation would be.